# I want xml data bind to Listbox using xmldatasource but i got an error

Tags: .net, xml, listbox

DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSourceNodeDescriptor' does not contain a property with the name 'name'.

The XML File:

```
 <Persons>
  <Person >
    <id>1</id>
    <name>jkl</name>
  </Person>
  <Person >
    <id>2</id>
    <name>jhk</name>
  </Person>
  <Person >
    <id>3</id>
    <name>kjh</name>
  </Person>
  <Person >
    <id>4</id>
    <name>jhkj</name>
  </Person>
  <Person >
    <id>5</id>
    <name>lj</name>
  </Person>
  <Person >
    <id>6</id>
    <name>jhkl</name>
  </Person>
  <Person >
    <id>7</id>
    <name>jhj</name>
  </Person>
</Persons>
```

I want bind to listbox with `datatextfield=name` and `datavaluefield=id` from xml.

aspx page code is like this:

```
   <asp:ListBox ID="lstBinddata" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"   DataSourceID="xmldata" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id">
   </asp:ListBox>
   <asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmldata" runat="server" DataFile="xmldata.xml"> </asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set up XPath property of XmlDataSource. I guess it should be:

```
XPath="Persons/Person"
```

Comment: No still i get an error like DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSourceNodeDescriptor' does not contain a property with the name 'name'.

Comment: I tried your code, changed XPath to just "Person" and exception disappear. But I don't have any data binded in ListBox. Interesting problem :), I don't know...

Comment: Must it be really done by XmlDataSource? There are many other ways which you can use.

Comment: i dont know exactly whether it can be done using XMLdatasource or not...but it can be done same way with binding dropdownlist from XML File thats sure.....i have done same way......

Answer (score 0):

You must use:

```
XPath("name")
```

Similarly, you can also use it to access the value of id:

```
XPath("id")
```